# Java stream : convert list of one object to other

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am trying to learn map function in Stream

```
public class EmployeeInformationTest {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      List<Employee> employees = Arrays.asList(
         new Employee("Jai"),
         new Employee("Adithya"),
         new Employee("Raja"));
      List<String> names = employees.stream()
         .map(s -> s.getEmployeeName())              // Lambda Expression
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
      System.out.println(names);
   }
}
```

we have above code and somehow it is giving us List of String from List of Employee. Say, we have other class Person in which we have field as name

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
}
```

so is it feasible via map or some other function in stream so that I can get the List of Person rather than List of String in above code

Comment: You already use `map` to convert a `Employee` into a `String`. Change that lambda to produce a `Person` instead and you're done (after changing the appropriate types of course). Alternatively you can add a second `map` to convert the `String` to a `Person`, but there's no good reason to make this two steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure thing, just change the `map` function to:

```
.map(s -> new Person(s.getEmployeeName()))
```

or if there is no such constructor:

```
.map(s -> { 
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setName(s.getEmployeeName());
    return p;
})
```